# How can I call function from directive after component's rendering?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-components

How can I call function from directive after component's rendering?

I have component:

```
export class Component {
  ngAfterContentInit() {
  // How can i call functionFromDirective()?
  }
}
```

And I want call this function:

```
export class Directive {

functionFromDirective() {
//something hapenns
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve Directive from Component's template with `ViewChild` like this:

```
@Directive({
  ...,
  selector: '[directive]',
})
export class DirectiveClass {
  method() {}
}
```

In your component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { DirectiveClass } from './path-to-directive'

@Component({
  ...,
  template: '<node directive></node>'
})
export class ComponentClass {
  @ViewChild(DirectiveClass) directive = null

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // How can i call functionFromDirective()?
    this.directive.method()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helps me.

Answer (score 8):

Calling the method from within a component is not a good idea.  Using a directive helps in a modular design, but when you call the method, you get a dependency from the component to the directive.

Instead, the directive should implement the AfterViewInit interface:

```
@Directive({
    ...,
    selector: '[directive]',
})
export class DirectiveClass implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
}
```

This way, your component doesn't have to know anything about the directive.

Comment: in the sequence of events, the Directive's AfterViewInit ran earlier than my Component's ngAfterContentChecked... but it depends upon a person's requirement