# Looking for a way to press a button in directive programmatically (Angular 2-5)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Hello guys I have an issue where i use this angular2 directive [ng2-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dual-list-box) and I have no idea on how to reset/move the value on the selected item to available item of this directive (went and open issue on github but no response yet) even if I use .reset() to reset the reactive form where this directive is in and set the value to null but still, no luck.

[Sample Image of the directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhwv.png)

But I got an idea. There is a move all selected item to available item button and I am going to press this button programmatically.
The problem is I don't know how to or if it is possible or not.

So I am looking for a way to press the specific button in the directive.
or are there any other way to workaround this.
I am in need of use this [ng2-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dual-list-box) badly.
Thank you in advanced guys!

Comment: you can use rxjs . create an new subject in an service then subscribe that in directive (new Subject<any>())

Comment: Based on the [demo](http://ng2-duallistbox-demo.surge.sh/) it looks like the ability to move an item from "selected" to "available" is built into the component.  I think I need some more help figuring out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MaxShenfield I am trying to reset the value of this [ng2-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dual-list-box) that I put it in some reactive form by using .reset() and set the value to null directly by onClick event function.The value got reset to null but the value in the selected items still there and not moving back to available items, then I am trying to move those items back to available item back by press the move all selected items to available button or execute the function programmatically but don't know how to or if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround!
I use ViewChild to call the function in the directive

[How can I call function from directive after component's rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549894/how-can-i-call-function-from-directive-after-components-rendering)